# How to access the insides of @cache in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, functools

Consider the code below, I want to access the key value pairs of the inbuilt cache that functools' cache provides.

```
@cache
def func(a1,a2):
    #code
    #...
    #return x
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't: *Users should only access the lru_cache through its public API: `cache_info`, `cache_clear`, and `f.__wrapped__`. The internals of the lru_cache are encapsulated for thread safety and to allow the implementation to change (including a possible C version)*

Answer (score 1):

As DeepSpace stated in his comment, you probably shouldn't and they did a good job to keep you from doing it.

The function afterwards is a wrapper cache object of which you of course can call `__dict__`, that won't do the trick sadly.
Because it is encapsulated and does not show it's internals at all.

One possible way I can imagine is writing a C function for python and then accessing bare memory, you'd then have to figure out in what structure these pairs are written to memory to access them, copy them? and then transform them back to python.
I strongly discourage you from doing this though because accessing memory you're not supposed to often leads to ugly errors that are hard to fix and figure out.

Besides from that you're left to `cache_info`, `cache_clear`.

Comment: You can also access *cache_parameters* but even that doesn't answer OP's question. The fact that this information is not formally exposed suggests that the underlying mechanism may be liable to change and even if it was possible to get this information *today* it might not work in a subsequent release of Python